# USB SSD not mounted but cannot format (LUKS format)

Tags: disk, luks, ssd, disk-encryption, journaling

I am trying to encrypt a USB SSD attached to my tiny server with LUKS.
The SSD is NOT mounted but still cannot format it.
(sda1 is my external drive)

```
sudo cryptsetup --verbose --verify-passphrase luksFormat /dev/sda1

Device /dev/sda1 is in use. Can not proceed with format operation.
Command failed with code -1 (wrong or missing parameters).
```

I tried the following:

```
sudo lsof | grep sda1

lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1002/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.

lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.

jbd2/sda1  411                            root  cwd       DIR      179,7     4096          2 /

jbd2/sda1  411                            root  rtd       DIR      179,7     4096          2 /

jbd2/sda1  411                            root  txt   unknown                                /proc/411/exe
```

```
ps -A | grep 411

411 ?        00:00:00 jbd2/sda1-8
```

All I found on internet about jbd2 is that “journaling block device”
Is it then something to do with journaling?

### answers to comments

```
$ lsblk /dev/sda1
NAME MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda1 8:1 0 931.5G 0 part


$ ls -l /sys/block/sda/sda1/holders/
total 0
```

```
sudo sfdisk -l /dev/sda
sudo password for xxx:
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: Portable SSD T5
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: xxx

Device Start End Sectors Size Type 
/dev/sda1 2048 1953523711 1953521664 931.5G Linux filesystem
```

```
fuser -m /dev/sda1
Nothing comes out
```

```
$ mount
/dev/mmcblk0p7 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=1867780k,nr_inodes=117763,mode=755)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup/unified type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd)
bpf on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=25,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
sunrpc on /run/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_9069.snap on /snap/core/9069 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core18_1751.snap on /snap/core18/1751 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snap-store_418.snap on /snap/snap-store/418 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/dev/mmcblk0p6 on /boot type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=399972k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
tmpfs on /run/user/1002 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=399972k,mode=700,uid=1002,gid=1002)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1002/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1002,group_id=1002)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
```

```
grep sda1 /proc/mounts
Nothing comes out but still cannot format disk.
```

Comment: The jbd2 process is unlikely to be the culprit (your grep matched its process name, not an open file handle). What is the partition table on sda?

Comment: Usually external media is automounted if the OS finds a way. If the disk is formatted with vfat/ntfs it will be mounted automatically.

Comment: Could you add the output of `mount`and `fuser -m /dev/sda1`?

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /sys/block/sda/sda1/holders/` or `lsblk /dev/sda1`?

Comment: I’ll be in front of a computer in a few hours time. Thanks

Comment: You shall not format comments; you were supposed to add the info to your question. I did that for you. Is there any output for `grep sda1 /proc/mounts`? If not: Try the `luksFormat` again. It really does not look like `sda1` is in use. And maybe it is not any more. Perhaps it was in use when you ran `cryptsetup` but is not any more.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.Could it be that one of my users "holds on" to the SSD somehow? I have 2 users, one is non sudoer and is always logged in the other one is an administrative account and I SSH with it.

Comment: Have you done what I told you, tried `cryptsetup` again? Unfortunately I have no more ideas what could be up there. A block device can be mounted but then we would see it in `/proc/mounts`. It can be "active part" of another block device but then we would see it in `lsblk` / the `holders` directory. I am not sure whether pure opening the device file would prevent formatting but we would see that in `fuser`. I can only suggest that you run `cryptsetup` through `strace` and try to find the syscall which fails (probably close to the error message). That may give a clue.